# Help solving a system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I need help solving the following system of ODE. The problem is not so much getting the final solution, but getting a clear view of the process to getting there.
The system is the following:
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dA(t)}{dt} = -aA(t) \\
\dfrac{dB(t)}{dt} = aA(t) - bB(t) \\
\dfrac{dC(t)}{dt} = bB(t)\\
\end{cases} $$

I know that $A = A(0)e^{-at}$, but I cannot figure out the expressions for B and C.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use undetermined coefficients to get $B$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Substitute the explicit solution for $A$ into the equation for $dB/dt$ to obtain a nonhomogeneous linear equation for $B$.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated we have that $A = A_0 e^{-at}$. We determine $B$. The differential equation for $B$ is a linear first order differential equation of the form:

$$ \frac{dB}{dt} + P(t)B = Q(t) $$

with $P(t) = b$ and $Q(t) = aA_0e^{-at}$. The solution of such an equation can be obtained by using an integrating factor $I(t)$ such that:

$$ I(t) \left( \frac{dB}{dt} + P(t)B \right) = \left(I(t)B\right)' = I(t)Q(t) $$

such a factor can be found to be:

$$ I(t) = e^{\int P(t) dt} $$

Now we have:

$$ \left(I(t) B \right)' = I(t)Q(t)$$

Integrating both sides we get:

$$B(t) = \frac{1}{I(t)} \left[ \int I(t)Q(t) dt + C\right]$$

And so:

$$ B(t) = \frac{aA_0}{b - a} e^{-at} + \left(B_0 - \frac{aA_0}{b - a} \right) e^{-bt}$$

with $B_0 = B(t = 0)$. We can verify this is the correct solution by substituting into the first equation:

$$ \frac{dB}{dt} + P(t)B = -\frac{a^2 A_0}{b - a} e^{-at} - b\left( B_0 - \frac{aA_0}{b - a} \right) e^{-bt} + b \left( \frac{aA_0}{b - a} e^{-at} + \left(B_0 - \frac{aA_0}{b - a} \right)e^{-bt} \right)$$
$$ = \left(-\frac{a}{b - a} + \frac{b}{b - a} \right) a A_0 e^{-at} $$
$$ = a A_0 e^{-at} = Q(t) $$

Comment: Note that $C(t)$ is readily computed: $$ C(t) = \int bB(t) dt= \int \alpha e^{-at} + \beta e^{-bt} dt = \alpha \frac{e^{-at}}{-a} + \beta \frac{e^{-bt}}{-b} + K$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear differential system of form $\dot{x}(t) = M x$, for below matrix $M$. The (matricial) solution for this ODE is $x(t, t_0, x_0) = \Phi(t, t_0) \, x_0$, such that matrix $\Phi(t, t_0)$ is called transition matrix. The transition matrix in this case is $\exp(M \, (t-t_0))$.

\begin{equation}
M = \begin{bmatrix}
-a&0&0 \\
a&-b&0 \\
0&b&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

There is no closed form based on exponential sum like you expect as an answer in general case. For this particular case, I performed the following Wolfram Alpha query for matrix $e^M$, let as call it N:

[image]

Therefore, the answer $x(t, t_0, x_0)$ you look for is given by $N^{t-t_0} \, x_0$